# WordPress Left Navigation

Tags: wordpress, custom-controls

This may be an odd question. I'm working on a website someone else built in WordPress. My understanding of the left navigation within the dashboard is that there are some default items that are there upon install like [pages], [posts], [plugins], and to get additional items to show up here you need to install a new plugin.

This site I'm working on has a few options in the left navigation [team members], [services] which do not appear to be tied to any particular 3rd party plugin.

In fact, it looks like they've used the plugin "Advanced Custom Fields" to create their own functionality so their users could easily add/remove team members from a custom built slider.

**My Question**
How do you get your own tab to show up in the dashboard's left navigation? Can you do this within a child theme, or do you need to modify the core WP files? Is there a particular folder or some documentation anyone could direct me to where I might learn more about how this is being connected behind the scenes?

Thank you kindly in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll preface this by saying:

## Never ever ever modify Core Files!

Whew! Now that that's out of the way, there may be a few plugins that do this for you, but I'm ultimately unfamiliar with any. The typical way to add Admin Items is with the [`add_menu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) and [`add_submenu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) functions. They're relatively straight forward to use.

Also, as a side note, when you add a [Custom Post Type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) with [`register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) (like what ACF does) there are options to add it to the menu, as well as what you want the labels and menu names to be.

If you're adding a Custom Post Type (like Team Members, Books, etc.) you'll almost certainly want to make use of the `labels` and `show_in_menu` arguments when you call `register_post_type()` to get the admin menu to show up. However, if you need to link to arbitrary URLs or custom dashboard pages, you'll want to make use of the `add_menu/submenu_page` functions above.

For instance, here's a simple snippet that will add a Stack Overflow link to the menu, you can drop this into a child theme, plugin, Must-Use plugin, etc:

```
function stack_overflow_admin_link(){
    echo '<script>window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com'; </script>';
}

add_menu_page( 'Stack Overflow', 'Stack Overflow', 'subscriber', 'stack-overflow', 'stack_overflow_admin_link', 'dashicons-external' );
```

Hope this helps!

Also I'll elaborate a little bit on my warning! Never ever modify core WordPress files. They will be overwritten with each and every WordPress update. WordPress is relatively well thought out and has countless [Action Hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) and [Filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) that let you inject, modify, remove, and otherwise manipulate data and the user experience without ever touching core files.

As an example, take a look at this screenshot:

[image: Restructuring WordPress]

I'm currently rebuilding a software suite from the ground-up using WordPress, but the standard WP Admin interface doesn't make sense in many of the contexts we need it, so our interface (a work in progress) looks like this, and it's all handled by a Must-Use plugin and touches **absolutely no core files**, it just uses clever manipulation of the hooks and filters available throughout WordPress

Comment: You are amazing. THANK YOU for your input on this.

Comment: You're welcome! If you need any further elaboration, feel free to shoot me a message through my website: https://xhynk.com/ - but those 3 functions should be enough to at least get you started!